# Much Ado About a Sequence

Tags: pattern, word-sequence

Here are two lists of five English words each. The first list is ordered in a certain way. Your challenge is to order the second list in the same way.

Here is some helpful (I hope) information:

- All ten words have a common property.
- The property has nothing to do with the meaning of the words
- Only a small percentage of English words have this property.
- Each of the words in each of the lists can be associated with a number from one to five according to this property.
- If you know the property, you can take any one word from either list and determine what number it is associated with.
- Not all words which have this property are unambiguously associated with a single number. I chose these to make it easy for you. :-)
- Five is not a hard limit. Some other words correspond to larger numbers.
- The first list is **not** in order from one to five

List 1:

> Cell
>   Canes
>   Flat
>   Nun
>   Live

List 2:

> Vet
>   Avid
>   Limb
>   Tasted
>   Bits

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The question has to do with

> inserting a letter O into a word to make another word.

Thus:

> cell**o**, can**o**es, fl**o**at, n**o**un, **o**live; and vet**o**, av**o**id, limb**o**, t**o**asted, **o**bits.

Here

> the positions where the O is to be inserted are 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 in the first case; 4, 3, 5, 2, 1 in the second.

So

> presumably we want reverse order for the second sequence as for the first: LIMB, VET, AVID, TASTED, BITS.

The title

> of course refers to putting the letters of the words about (i.e., around) nothing (i.e., O).